# Taking a sentence long string and scanning any words AND keeping all the special characters in Java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am working in Java and trying to take a sentence of words and special characters (quotes, periods, commas, etc as well as any/all white spaces) and manipulate them. I need to be able to push the words onto a stack (which I am comfortable doing), but any other characters besides the letters of the alphabet need to stay the same.

I cannot think of an easy way to use the Scanner and Next() without bringing in one of the special characters with it. Should I just go character by character to see if there are multiple letters in a row, make it a new string for that word? I feel like there has to be a more elegant way to do that.

Thanks for any/all help!

Comment: are you just trying to get rid of special characters in a string?

Answer (score 1):

next() can read the input only till the space. It can't read two words separated by space. Also, next() places the cursor in the same line after reading the input.

nextLine() reads input including space between the words (that is, it reads till the end of line \n). Once the input is read, nextLine() positions the cursor in the next line.

for reading the entire line you can use nextLine()

Comment: And then you can use `split()` on the resulting `String` to split the line into words easily.

Comment: So if I have the String: "Hello!    @we're here!" (there are three spaces between the ! and @, but it is not showing up here), how would split it so there would be 8 strings in the array, "Hello", "!    @" (with the three spaces showing), "we", "'", "re", " ", "here", and "!"? I want to break it up at every time there are letters unless they are consecutive.